# Heatmap don't show all categories in yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to render a heatmap graphic but not all of yAxis are displayed in the chart, even putting turboThreshold to 0

My jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/camilo17/zk70smv8/

My series array

```
series: [{
      name: 'Trafico por horas',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [ ... ],
      turboThreshold: 0,
}]
```

At the end of categories there is a "68" I don't know what does it means.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution - set step label's property to 1.

```
  labels: {
    step: 1
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d5u09xnt/